# Nodejs simple socket.io example not working

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've the following **Server Side** Code:

```
        var express = require('express')
          , http    = require('http')
          , routes  = require('./routes')
          , io      = require('socket.io')
          , factory = require('./serverfactory.js');
          var  app  = express();

          var server = app.listen(3000);
          io = io.listen(server);

          io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){

            console.log('new user');

            socket.emit('hail','mysimplemsg');
            socket.on('customevent',function(msg){
                console.log(msg);       
            });
          });



        //var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

        // Configuration

        app.configure(function(){
          app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
          app.set('view engine', 'jade');
          app.use(express.bodyParser());
          app.use(express.methodOverride());
          app.use(app.router);
          app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
        });

        app.configure('development', function(){
          app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
        });

        app.configure('production', function(){
          app.use(express.errorHandler());
        });

        // Routes
        app.get('/', routes.index);
```

And this is the **client side :**

```
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    socket.emit('customevent','work');
    socket.on('hail',function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    });
```

I am expecting that my `git console` outputs `new user` (which it does) then it should output `work` (which it does not) then i get a msg in my browser console `mysimplemsg` (which it does not).

Whats going on why the event at server side that is `customevent` is not called and why the event at the client side that is `hail` is not called ?

Comment: Check out @nFreeze's answer below, and check out http://socket.io/#how-to-use for more examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

It was working fine on `opera` but not on `chrome and firefox`. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350279/socket-io-does-not-work-on-firefox-chrome) link in which the guy says to insert this code snippet on the server side.

```
io.configure('development', function(){
  io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);
});
```

It's working fine now.

Comment: sorry I forgot mention the browser issue in the question.

Comment: hmm, i want to use socket.io for websocket, not for xhr-polling. not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that you are emitting **customevent** from the client *before* you are connected. Try adding a connect handler and moving your client side emit into it:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');    
socket.on('hail',function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
});
socket.on('connect',function(){
                      console.log('connected to socket.io server');
                      socket.emit('customevent','work');
                    });
```

If the connect handler is *not* hit then verify that you are referencing the client side socket.io javascript library correctly (jade syntax):

```
script(type='text/javascript',src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
```

Comment: thnx for your response i did as you said but still i can only see `new user` message in the log no `work` message is displayed in the log in my git.

Comment: the `socket.on('connect')` is not working. I debug the code and the client is not sending anything in the log.What could be the problem ?

Comment: This code works for me. Verify that you are hosting the socket.io client library correctly.

Comment: Yeah I am hosting it correctly.I don't why this event is not fired it driving me crazy.I am having this problem from 3 days.

Comment: I copy pasted the exact same code from `socket.io/#how-to-use` but still the same problem.

Comment: i have the same problem with simple example snippets. 
i can see in chrome that the websocket connection is up, and see a 'user connected' message on the server. but sending/receiving messages with emit or send is not working. the only eventhandler which works is the connect-handler on the serverside...