# NodeJS work fine with IE but unstable with Chrome, Firefox and Opera

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am working on a chat system using nodejs and socket.io. So far my application work perfectly with Internet Explorer 10 but most of the time i can't send message on Firefox or Chrome or Opera (but i can still read message sent from IE in Chrome/Firefox/Opera). All my browser is updated to newest version, and without any addon/extension. I have also tried several different free port but without any result. I am working on Windows 7 environment and all my test was done locally.

I have no idea what went wrong, been scratching my head for last few hours but can't figure anything. I am new to node.js so please help !

Edit : I tried to force the transport to websocket by using io.set('transports', ['websocket']); and now IE stop working as well, so it seem before the reason IE work is socket.io force IE to use xhr-polling instead of websocket.

My code is as below (taken from http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socketio-and-expressjs--net-31708)

**Server index.js**

```
    var express = require("express");
    var app = express();
    var port = 3700;


    app.set('views', __dirname + '/tpl');
    app.set('view engine', "jade");
    app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);
    app.get("/", function(req, res){
        res.render("page");
    });

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));
    console.log(port);
    console.log(io);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log("connect");
        socket.emit('message', { message: 'welcome to the chat !' });
        socket.on('send', function (data) {
            io.sockets.emit('message', data);
        });
    });

    console.log("Listening on port " + port);
```

**The view**

```
    doctype html
    head
        title= "Real time web chat"
        script(src='/chat.js')
        script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')       
        body
            #content(style='width: 500px; height: 300px; margin: 0 0 20px 0; border:         solid 1px #999; overflow-y: scroll;')
```

.controls
            | Name: 
            input#name(style='width:350px;')
            br
            input#field(style='width:350px;')
            input#send(type='button', value='send')

**Chat.js**

```
    window.onload = function() {

var messages = [];
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3700');
var field = document.getElementById("field");
var sendButton = document.getElementById("send");
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var name = document.getElementById("name");

socket.on('message', function (data) {
    if(data.message) {
        messages.push(data);
        var html = '';
        for(var i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {
            html += '<b>' + (messages[i].username ? messages[i].username : 'Server') + ': </b>';
            html += messages[i].message + '<br />';
        }
        content.innerHTML = html;
    } else {
        console.log("There is a problem:", data);
    }
});

sendButton.onclick = function() {
    if(name.value == "") {
        alert("Please type your name!");
    } else {
        var text = field.value;
        socket.emit('send', { message: text, username: name.value });
    }
};
```

}

Edit : According to the similar question [Socket.io does not work on Firefox & Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350279/socket-io-does-not-work-on-firefox-chrome?rq=1) it was fixed by adding below code into chat.js. I did it and it work on chrome/firefox/opera now but it is forcing the browser to use long-pooling/ajax instead of websocket, and i want my browser to use websocket (chrome/firefox should be able to support websocket better than IE i think ?)

```
    io.configure('development', function(){
      io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);
    });
```

Comment: Do you have a load balancer in front of your server or anything like that?

Comment: Sorry for my late comment, no i don't have any load balancer. Actually i am testing at local server, xampp 3.1.0 and windows 7